# Problema al instalar Swoole

Tags: php, linux, debian, swoole

Estoy intentando instalar Swoole en diferentes distribuciones de Linux, pero me encuentro con este problema: Al hacer el listado de los modulos instalandos en PHP aparece Swoole.

[image: Lista de modulos de PHP instalados]

Reinicio el Apache e intento ejecutar una clase de Swoole, pero recibo el siguiente error:

[image: error en logs]

Francamente no sé que estoy haciendo mal o cual es el problema. ¿Alguien tiene una idea? He probado en Centos, Ubuntu, y Debian con el mismo resultado =/.

```
 <?php $server = new Swoole\HTTP\Server("127.0.0.1", 9501);

$server->on("start", function (Swoole\Http\Server $server) {
    echo "Swoole http server is started at http://127.0.0.1:9501\n";
});

$server->on("request", function (Swoole\Http\Request $request, Swoole\Http\Response $response) {
    $response->header("Content-Type", "text/plain");
    $response->end("Hello World\n");
});

$server->start();
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, incluye el código de ese `1.php` que estás probando.

Comment: Ya lo he hecho amigo! solo es un simple script para ver su funcionalidad.

Comment: Revisa la versión que estás usando, pues en [el repo oficial](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src) hay `Swoole\WebSocket\Server` y `Swoole\Http\Request $request` (o response), entre otras opciones... pero no veo implementación de Swoole\Http\Server. De hecho, no sería [la primera vez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57389305/236345) que la documentación del sitio oficial no coincide con el repo.

Comment: [Fri Jan 08 17:51:11.655025 2021] [php7:error] [pid 2575] [client 23.227.192.85:56286] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Swoole\\WebSocket\\Server' not found in /var/www/html/1.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/1.php on line 2     Honestamente no creo que sea un error de clases si no de la instalación, no entiendo por que no detecta el modulo ya modifique el php.ini y agregue al extensión.